# Automatically updating backbone underscore template

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a backbone collection that uses the fetch method to get an array of objects from the server and what I am trying to do is just loop through each object in the template and read its properties. Following is the collection and the template

```
APP.MyObjects = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/api/objects/',
    model: APP.MyObject,
    initialize: function() {
        this.fetch();
    }
});
APP.myObjects = new APP.MyObjects(); // Fetches the data
```

Now in the template what I am trying to do is:

```
<% _.each(APP.myObjects.toJSON(), function(obj) {%>
    <%= obj.title %>
<% }); %>
```

The issue I am facing is that `Collection.fetch` call is asynchronous so by the time the template is rendered the length of `APP.myObjects.toJSON` is `0`. So I don't get to see the object properties and even after the async fetch call is completed the template does not get updated.

**Question**:

How can I have the template update automatically when the `APP.myObjects` list is updated or changed ? In Angular we use `watch` for something that I am trying to achieve, I am fairly new to backbone and underscore, so I want to know what is the best way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to add this line in my view's `initialize` method to make sure the template is re-rendered after the update.

```
MyObjectListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.listenTo(APP.myObjects, 'update', this.render);
    }
});
```